# Object.defineProperty and return values

Tags: javascript, object, setter, getter, defineproperty

I'm playing around with a javascript object that defines some getters and setters using the Object.defineProperty method.

```
function User() {       
    var _username;  
    var _id;

    Object.defineProperty(User, 'id', {
        get: function() {
            return _username;
        }       
    });         

    Object.defineProperty(User, 'username', {
        get: function() {
            return _username;
        },
        set: function(username) {
            this._username = username;          
        }
    }); 
}
```

For one of the properties (id), I only want a getter. Originally I had a typo and it was returning the value of `_username`, but I quickly realized that the above did not work. Just for curiosity sake though, I'm trying to understand why it didn't work as expected. If I did the following:

```
var u = new User();
u.username = 'bob';
alert(u.username);
alert(u.id);
```

the last statement would alert `undefined` instead of `bob`. Why is that? And is there a way to get it to return another property?

Comment: You're defining properties on `User`, not on `u`. Try `User.username` to see it work - and then fix your code not to alter the constructor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the properties on `this` instead of the constructor function

```
function User(params) {       
   var _username;

   Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        get: function() {
            return _username;
        }       
   });         

   Object.defineProperty(this, 'username', {
        get: function() {
            return _username;
        },
        set: function(username) {
            _username = username;          
        }
   }); 
   if (params && params.username) {
       this.username = params.username;
   }
}
User.prototype.stringify = function () {
    return JSON.stringify({ username: this.username});
}
```

Comment: Changing it to `this` doesn't seem to work. If I do that and I run the user test code in my original post, the first and second alert both output `undefined`.

Comment: This should work, could you show me what you did (in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example) ?

Comment: If you replace `User` with `this` you're half way :) I've made more changes to your code, I admit they are subtile! Note that you have `var _username` and `this._username`!!

Comment: Follow-up question. With the above solution  implemented, why can't I do something like this: `var u1 = new User(); u1.username = 'a'; var u2 = new User(); u2.username = 'b';` This is essentially what I am trying to achieve; create distinct objects and assign different values to them.

Comment: But you can. What is exactly the problem you're experiencing ?

Comment: My bad. Was using an out of date version. Please ignore.

Comment: One thing I notice now though is that I can't stringify an instance of User. It ends up being {} without any of the properties or values. Why is that?

Comment: JSON.stringify will strip off things like functions. Because you've defined a getter/setter on `username` its stripped off now. For example, if you do: `x = new User;x.abc = 1;JSON.stringify(x);` you see what I mean. You could of course define your own `stringify` function (checkout my origin post)

Comment: What about the reverse now? Would I defined a parse method to return a new instance of User?

Comment: No, just accept an json object in the constructor function and initialize it inside there, like: `var x = new User({username: 'A'});`